# What does 얘오 mean after a name?

Tags: names

In the Korean show *The Secret Life of My Secretary*, when the character Veronica Park introduces herself, she says her name "Veronica Park" (pronounced like an English speaker), followed immediately by something like 얘오 or 예오 (sounds to me like "yay-oh"). What does this word or suffix after her name mean?

For an example, see here at 2:47  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2gyBV3W5Xo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you heard is '베로니카 파*크*'**예요**. However, the explanations given here are incorrect. The following is the correct rule.

> If there is a **bottom** consonant in the final character of the name, then it's **name + 이에요**, e.g. 홍길동 (there is a consonant ㅇ below 도 in 동), 아이린 (there is a consonant ㄴ below 리 in 린), 고두심  (there is a consonant ㅁ below 시 in 심)

> Otherwise, it's almost always **name + 예요**, e.g. 배철수 (no consonant below 수), 김태희 (no consonant below 희), 이순재 (no consonant below 재), 현아  (no consonant below 아)

Therefore, it's "베로니카 파크"예요 because there's no bottom consonant below 크.

I would like to point out that in the colloquial context no one really cares for the difference between 예요 and 이에요. I highly doubt that most Koreans would even be aware of this rule in the first place :D

Comment: Thanks! What is the source of the quoted section in your answer?

Comment: Hey there! A lot of the questions on this forum are answered on korean.go.kr, a website run by the Ministry of Culture. The answers are almost always spot on as they're presumably vetted by those who meet certain academic credentials. The problem is that it's entirely in Korean. For my response above you can refer to the following link: https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=97282

Answer (score 1):

That is "에요". Means "am/is".

`박 베로니카에요` = `(I) am Veronica Park` The subject has been omitted.

Answer (score 1):

It's 예요 which is a form of 이다 contracted from 이에요, coloquially the form 에요 is more common. Both are contractions of 이다 in the 해요체 speech level which presents itself as 이어요 and gets umlauted into 에요